# Using XPath Expression in Loop

Tags: java, xml, loops, xpath

I am using the following XPath expression to loop through a XML document:

```
/templatedatabase/datatypes/integers/integer[index]/@defaultvalue
```

Method header:

```
private static String getGetDefaultValueByIndex(Document doc, XPath xpath, int index)
```

"index" is a parameter in the method. The problem is the following:
The query doesn´t return a value if I put a number in the method header as parameter.(e.g. `getGetDefaultValueByIndex(doc, xpath, 1)`).

But if I, for instance put a number like 1,2,... in place of index in the query I get the data I want from the XML file while executing the same method. The XPath query is correct and the method is working if I put in the number manually in the query like this:

```
/templatedatabase/datatypes/integers/integer[1]/@defaultvalue
```

--> This returns a value.

However:

```
getGetDefaultValueByIndex(doc, xpath, 1)
/templatedatabase/datatypes/integers/integer[index]/@defaultvalue
```

--> This doesn´t return a value.

I don´t really understand why this is not working. I can´t imagine that you can´t loop through a XPath Query using a variable.

The complete code of the method:

```
private static String getGetDefaultValueByIndex(Document doc, XPath xpath, int index) {
         String DefaultValue = null;
         try {
                String expression = "/templatedatabase/datatypes/integers/integer" + "[index]" + "/@defaultvalue";
                DefaultValue = (String) xPath.evaluate(expression, doc, XPathConstants.STRING);     
                System.out.println(DefaultValue);
     } catch(XPathExpressionException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
         return DefaultValue;
     }
```

}

Comment: Do you mean: "/templatedatabase/datatypes/integers/integer" + [index] + "/@defaultvalue"; ?

Comment: Yes, but the query still doesn´t return a value when using index. It is still working when I use a number instead of index though.

The query: 
/templatedatabase/datatypes/integers/integer" + "[index]" + "/@defaultvalue
--> Still returns no value.(Index is 1 in method header.)

"/templatedatabase/datatypes/integers/integer" + "[1]" + "/@defaultvalue"
--> Returns value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the quotes in the wrong place, try:

```
String expression = "/templatedatabase/datatypes/integers/integer[" + index + "]/@defaultvalue";
```

This will include the *value* of the `index` parameter into the XPath expression, rather than the literal string `"index"`.

A word of warning though - constructing XPath expressions dynamically using string concatenation is fine when you're dealing with numeric variables like `index`, but if you want to provide arbitrary user-specified *string* parameters to the expression it's safer to use a static XPath expression including XPath variables like

```
"/templatedatabase/datatypes[@name=$targetName]"
```

and define an `XPathVariableResolver` to inject the actual values.